# Problem About Inequality

Tags: inequality

$1+$$\sqrt{n^2}-9n+20$ > $\sqrt{n^2}-7n+12$ How many  positive integers $n$ which supplies this equality?

I couldn't solve this problem, it seems too hard.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{n^2}=n$

Comment: Biraz yardimci ol

Comment: I need help more.

Comment: If you use the hint that I wrote, you get

$-8n+21>-6n+12$, and

$9>2n$.

Comment: @Electro Does the inequality really look like this: $1+\sqrt{n^2-9n+20}>\sqrt{n^2-7n+12}$?

Answer (score 0):

$$1+\sqrt{n^2}-9n+20 > \sqrt{n^2}-7n+12$$

$$1-9n+20 > -7n+12$$

Can you solve the problem now?

Comment: can you give more detail?

Comment: add $9n$ to both sides.

Comment: Thanks... It's so nice for me

Answer (score 0):

it can be written as
$$1+n-9n+20>n-7n+12$$
$$21-8n>-6n+12$$
$$9>2n$$ and from here $$n<\frac{9}{2}$$ and the solution set is given by $$\{1,2,3,4\}$$

Comment: yeh i' here in Bremerhaven on the Mathematical Olympiad-Bundesolympiade, thx

Comment: Nice man, I'm honorred that talked with you.